# Run a script.php on cron job on linux/apache server but restrict public access to the php file

Tags: php, cron, public

I have this script.php file which i want to run as a cron job on my linux/apache server.

However, i do not want public to access www.mycompanyname.com/script.php and also run the script concurrently.

How can we prevent that? How can we restrict the script to the server's access only?
Is it using chmod or setting something inside .htaccess file, something along the line?

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have something like a `public_html` directory, in which you have all the phps. Just put it outside of that directory.

Comment: ohh, sounds logical i never thought of..  i probably forgot the public_html is the root mapped to the hostname instead of the outside directories. As my script.php requires apache to run, i presumme, directory outside the public_html is still runnable ?

Comment: Sure! you just need permission for your user in the dir (I assume the cron runs as your user)

Answer (score 9):

You can do this as the first line of PHP in `script.php`...

```
if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    exit;
}
```

If someone hits your script via HTTP, the `PHP_SAPI` will be `cgi` I believe, and not `cli`, causing your script to exit straight away.

Of course, this relies on your cron calling `php script.php`.

You could also send...

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

... or of course, leave it outside your web root.

Answer (score 6):

If you put the script outside of the webroot folder it will not be accessible through your webserver.
e.g.
your webroot is at /var/www/public_html/
you put the script.php outside of that folder, for example: /var/www/

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1.**

If you are executing PHP directly from the Cron Job e.g. php /path/to/your_script.php then add the following line at the top of your PHP script:

```
if (php_sapi_name() !='cli') exit;
```

**Method 2.**

If the Cron Job uses wget, curl or lynx to run your script via its URL, then insert this code at the top of your PHP script (change the User Agent string to one known only by you) :

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != 'yourSecretAgent') exit;
```

You will also have to set the User Agent in the Cron Job; as in this wget example:

```
wget -O - --user-agent=“yourSecretAgent” http://example.com/your_script.php
```